# Storing local Cell-id to lat/long database, to accommodate the same range for the new offline google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, offline, cellid

I have read many q and a's about this subject, but not quite what I am asking. Is there a way to store the cell-id  to latitude - longitude database for the local area only, like the google maps new offline feature, could you get the localized information and store it, to cover the same ground as the map?, I am looking to make an android app which works offline, which is power efficient, and this is the best option that I have thought of. I have checked opencellid, and the kml file it provides, would that be enough to find the location without an internet connection or gps?

Answer (score 0):

You could explore the offline database option provided by [LocationAPI.org](http://www.locationapi.org) to use for your app. Storing 36 million+ cells offline would be a task though!